# Expo in Bare react native cli- npx react-native run-ios issue

Tags: react-native, expo

I recently developed an app in bare react native cli and got a task to integrate biometric login.
I tried some react native packages but it wasn't maintained by anyone for a long time.
So I installed expo modules in my react native project and integrated expo biometric authentication in it and it was perfectly working in android.

I tried running it from xcode for IOS and it was running perfectly fine and no error was encountered.
But in IOS when i run npx react-native run-ios it isn't running properly in any physical device or simulators.

I am also able to archive from xcode also without any issues.

These are the issue i'm facing

````
'[' -z export:embed ']'
'[' -z '' ']'
COMPOSE_SOURCEMAP_PATH=/Users/mac/ReactNative/midhun/N5_m/Code/MobileApp/newN5/node_modules/react-native/scripts/compose-source-maps.js
[[ -z '' ]]
CONFIG_ARG=
BUNDLE_FILE=/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/N5Shield-dczasgqmauwfbybuawsomskjbuft/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/main.jsbundle
EXTRA_ARGS=
case "$PLATFORM_NAME" in
BUNDLE_PLATFORM=ios
'[' '' = YES ']'
EMIT_SOURCEMAP=
[[ ! -z '' ]]
PACKAGER_SOURCEMAP_FILE=
[[ '' == true ]]
[[ true != false ]]
[[ false == false ]]
EXTRA_ARGS=' --minify false'
/Users/mac/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.0/bin/node /Users/mac/ReactNative/midhun/N5_m/Code/MobileApp/newN5/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/bin/cli export:embed --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --reset-cache --bundle-output /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/N5Shield-dczasgqmauwfbybuawsomskjbuft/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/main.jsbundle --assets-dest /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/N5Shield-dczasgqmauwfbybuawsomskjbuft/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/N5Shield.app --minify false
Error: GetEnv.NoInteger: is not an integer.
Error: GetEnv.NoInteger: is not an integer.
at Object.int (/Users/mac/ReactNative/midhun/N5_m/Code/MobileApp/newN5/node_modules/getenv/index.js:38:13)
at /Users/mac/ReactNative/midhun/N5_m/Code/MobileApp/newN5/node_modules/getenv/index.js:84:27
at get RCT_METRO_PORT [as RCT_METRO_PORT] (/Users/mac/ReactNative/midhun/N5_m/Code/MobileApp/newN5/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/build/env.js:16:33)
at getDefaultConfig (/Users/mac/ReactNative/midhun/N5_m/Code/MobileApp/newN5/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/build/ExpoMetroConfig.js:196:36)
at Object. (/Users/mac/ReactNative/midhun/N5_m/Code/MobileApp/newN5/metro.config.js:38:23)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/N5Shield-dczasgqmauwfbybuawsomskjbuft/Build/Intermediates.noindex/N5Shield.build/Release-iphonesimulator/N5Shield.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh (in target 'N5Shield' from project 'N5Shield')
(1 failure)

Node.js v20.11.0```


Create a bare react native project (npx react-native init appName)
Install expo modules
Make the changes in the IOS part by following the document.
https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/

run npx react-native run-ios (in simulator or in a physical device) from terminal.
````